# Extending Eloquent models, more magic methods

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Situation: In my work they have conventions on their database, table and column names, which are a bit long and repetitive. Being used to Eloquent I figured it wouldn't be much trouble to reimplement `__get` and `__set` methods, and not making lots of getters. Something like this (`toConvention` implements company's conventions):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class CompanyModel extends Model {
    public function __get($key){
        return $this->getAttribute($this->toConvention($key));
    }
    public function __set($key){
        return $this->setAttribute($this->toConvention($key));
    }
}
```

Which works well, for retrieving attributes, but not for retrieving relationships. Here are the implementations:

```
use App\CompanyModel as Model
class Location extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tablename';
    protected $primaryKey = 'primarykeycolumn';
    //...
    public function comissionCurrency(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Currency', 'foreign', 'other');
    }
}

use App\CompanyModel as Model
class Currency extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tablename';
    protected $primaryKey = 'primarykeycolumn';
    //...
}
```

When requesting for attributes, like `$location->name`, or `$location->comission_currency_id` everything works as expected, retrieving the corresponding column name. But when I try to retrieve the `belongsTo` relationship, after using `toSql()` I see almost the correct query formed: `select * from table where table.column is null` the `is null` part should be comparing with the corresponding id.
I know it's due to my implementation, because when I `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` everything works ok. Funny thing is that when I use Eloquent's model on the child model and the reimplemented on the other, it works to (but I'm not able to use my magic methods in the child model, in the parent one fetched from the relationship I can...)

I haven't figured out which method to reimplement to make this work by reading Eloquent's code, any ideas, or suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you specify the database name once and for all in your .env file?

Comment: Yes, the `tablename`, `primarykeycolumn`, `foreign` and `other` are just placeholders. As I wrote, I know it's problem of my reimplementation of the model, because when I replace `use App\CompanyModel` with `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` everything works fine.

Comment: I meant more your statement `In my work they have conventions on their database names, which are a bit long and repetitive`. If you set the datasbase name once, it doesn't matter how long it is.

Comment: Oh, ok, also columns from tables, the database name is not a problem, should've clarified that. I'll edit xD